# TCP connection - Bare Metal vs libvirt - VM

Tags: sockets, tcp, virtualization, kvm, libvirt

I performed a TCP connection between two directly connected 'bare metal'. I observed 90% of link as throughput.

When performing TCP connection between sender 'bare metal' to receiver VM, I observe 20% of link as throughput.

VM is set to the MAX core allocation and RAM allocation of Node. I also tried core affinity setting.

Can anybody suggest a reason for this variation like core allocation of the VM to Node?